# How can I tell what's the meaning of “just”: only, justice, or recently?

Tags: adverbs, ambiguity

Just– meaning *only* is adjective.

Just–meaning *justice* is adjective.

Just–referring to *recently* is adverb.

How can I know what is *justice* or *only*?

Below, I refer to *only*, but someone told me this means ***justice***

> You are anti-girlish, so you distort girlish man, by your just opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When "just" means "right, appropriate, according to justice", it is an ordinary adjective, which means that, like all ordinary adjectives, it is placed after the determiner:

> I think that would be **the just** way to handle the situation.
>
> They have received more than **their just** portion.
>
> We have to act in accordance with **those just** principles.

When "just" means "only", it is placed *before* the determiner:

> Don't wash the whole car, **just the** front end.
>
> They usually keep it almost a secret, telling **just their** best friends.
>
> I have other reasons, too, not **just those** reasons.